# aligned environment, align numbers to right

Tags: equations

I have an "equation", where I simply want to give some constant values. I'm aligning on the equation symbols, but as the numbers have different amounts of digits, I would also like to align the numbers to the right:

[image: alignment]

LaTeX currently looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \text{first value} &= 12 & \\
    \text{second value} &= 1234 & \\
    \text{third one} &= 1234567 &
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to align to the right with `aligned`? Are there any other packages for achieving this (I would like to stick to the equation if possible, for consistency reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
    \text{first value} &={}& 12  \\
    \text{second value} &={}& 1234  \\
    \text{third one} &={}& 1234567
    \end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I have just moved the `&` before the numbers and used `alignedat` (thanks to egreg).

[image]

This is with `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{$#1$}}  %% change 1.5cm to fit in the largest integer
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \text{first value} &= \mybox{12}  \\
    \text{second value} &= \mybox{1234}  \\
    \text{third one} &= \mybox{1234567}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option with a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}      %% or \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{r!{$=$}r}
    first value & 12  \\
    second value & 1234  \\
    third one & 1234567 
    \end{tabular}      %% or \end{center}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Here you can use `begin{center}` or `\centering` (within a group) instead of `\begin{equation*}`.

[image]

Comment: Your first and second solutions seem to insert far more white space to the right of the `=` sign than to the left (even when looking at just the third row). Is there a way to make the position of the `=` sign more centered?

Comment: `alignedat` would be better

Comment: @egreg Ah! missed it. Thanks and I have changed accordingly.

Comment: @HarishKumar The difference, as you know, is that `aligned` adds a padding between `rl` groups of columns, while `alignedat` doesn't; `\begin{alignedat}{2}` would be sufficient, the argument is the number of `rl` column groups.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I apologise. I wrote in a hurry (as always) and missed the fine details. Thanks (as always) and corrected. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `array` environment inside an `equation*` environment and auto-generate the `=` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro and "equation*" environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{array}{r@{{}={}}r} % "@{{}={}}" inserts correctly-spaced equal sign between the columns
    \text{first value}  &      12  \\
    \text{second value} &    1234  \\
    \text{third one}    & 1234567 
\end{array} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using `align*`. In order to have a correct spacing around the = sign, you need to ass  a pair of`{}` at least in the line that contains the longest number.

I loaded  `empheq`to have an easy way of adding the vertical line at the right of the equations. Ot loads  `mathtools`, that in turn loads (and corrects 2 bugs of) `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}[right =\color{IndianRed1}\vrule width1pt]
    \text{first value} &=   &12   \\
    \text{second value} & ={} &   1234  \\
    \text{third one} &=  & 1234567
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]